# Program not allowing chosen number output to run

Tags: python

This is the code that does not seem to work:

```
    choice = input()
    if input() == "1":
        circle()
    elif input() == "2":
        square()
    elif input() == "3":
        triangle()
    while input() != ("1" or "2" or "3"):
        print("You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.")
        choice = input()
        if input() == "1":
            circle()
        elif input() == "2":
            square()
        elif input() == "3":
            triangle()
```

Basically the part that checks the correct number  has been input does not seem to work and I don't know why, its only a logic error and i think its something to do with this part:

```
while input() != ("1" or "2" or "3"):
    print("You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while input() != ("1" or "2" or "3"):` is not correct.

`("1" or "2" or "3")` is a logical statement and resolves to the first non-empty or non-zero item:

```
>>> "1" or "2" or "3"
'1'
```

So the statement resolves to:

```
while input() != '1':
```

To correct it, use `not in` and a tuple:

```
while input() not in ("1", "2", "3"):
```

Alternatively, use the following pattern when asking for input and have a dispatch table of functions to eliminate the multiple `if` statements:

```
def circle():
    print('circle')

def square():
    print('square')

def triangle():
    print('triangle')

funcs = {'1':circle,
         '2':square,
         '3':triangle}

while True:
    choice = input()
    if choice in ('1','2','3'):
        break
    print("You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.")

funcs[choice]()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're storing the input as `choice` but then calling `input()` again instead of using the value you already read.

Additionally, you can simplify this code significantly.

You should instead do the following:

```py
choice = input()
while choice not in ("1", "2" ,"3"):
    print("You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.")
    choice = input()

if choice == "1":
    circle()
elif choice == "2":
    square()
elif choice == "3":
    triangle()
```

Comment: It works the first time, but if i enter the wrong number again for a few more times, it only does what i need it to after about 3 repeated wrong answers

Comment: @ExiusCain I'm not sure what your question is. It would helpful if you could provide your full code, as well as an example of the input you're giving at the output you're expecting.

Comment: It works the first time, but if i enter the wrong number again for a few more times, it only does what i need it to after about 3 repeated wrong answers. This is what it outputs:                                                       If you want to output a certain shape, enter the number next to it.
Please enter the the corresponding number of the shape you want to see.
5
You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.
5
5
5
5

Comment: It works the first time, but if i enter the wrong number again for a few more times, it only does what i need it to after about 3 repeated wrong answers. This is what it outputs:                                                       If you want to output a certain shape, enter the number next to it.
Please enter the the corresponding number of the shape you want to see.
5
You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.
5
5
5
5

Comment: You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.                                                                                                  that is the final part of the code

Comment: @ExiusCain can you post your full program?

Comment: @ExiusCain I've updated my answer with a full solution. Does this do what you need?

Comment: No, it can now see what numbers are incorrect but now any number entered is deemed incorrect, i shall show you the entire code with what you have given me added on to it.

Comment: def main_seg():
    print("Oh hai! This program draws a shape.")
    print("""Currently we do the following shapes:
Circle - 1
Square - 2
Triangle - 3
""")
    print("If you want to output a certain shape, enter the number next to it.")
    choose_SHAPE()

Comment: this is the next part, too many characters                                                                         
def choose_SHAPE():
    print("Please enter the the corresponding number of the shape you want to see.")
    choice = input()
    while choice != (1 or 2 or 3):
        print("You have not chosen a correct number. Please try again.")
        choice = input()
    if choice == "1":
        circle()
    elif choice == "2":
        square()
    elif choice == "3":
        triangle()
main_seg()

Comment: @ExiusCain Ah, I see the problem. I've edited my answer to correct it.